# Hyperkähler structure of Quaternion

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, quaternions, kahler-manifolds, almost-complex

I think there was an issue with the question I asked earlier.

I want to prove that the quaternion is a hyperkahler manifold. I know that there is a natural metric $\rho$ on that given by $\rho(a,a)=a·a^{*}$ which is just the product in $\mathbb{H}$ which gives a manifold structure to $\mathbb{H}$ which is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

So how could we constructer the hyperkahler structure?

Comment: How can a 3 real-dimensional manifold be hyperkahler?

Comment: @Three aggies, maybe I was wrong. I just know that the quaternion group is a hyperkahler manifold, so I want to give it a manifold structure. Also that unit quaternion is isomorphic to 3-sphere, so I ask this question. So you mean we have another way to give $H$ manifold structure?

Comment: Why don't you use $U(1,\mathbb{H}) \stackrel{\simeq_\psi}{\longrightarrow} SU(2,\mathbb{C}) \stackrel{\operatorname{Ad}}{\longrightarrow} SO(\mathfrak{su(2,\mathbb{C}}))$ to give the unit quaternions a manifold structure? $\psi $ is given by $\psi(x_1\mathbf{1}+x_2\mathbf{i}+x_3\mathbf{j}+x_4\mathbf{k}) = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\mathbf{1}+x_2\mathbf{i} & -x_3\mathbf{1}+x_4\mathbf{i} \\x_3\mathbf{1}+x_4\mathbf{i} & x_1\mathbf{1}-x_2\mathbf{i} \end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: Note: this question has changed significantly since the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, for any $q \in \mathbb{H}$, $T_q\mathbb{H} \simeq \mathbb{H}$, and consider as complex structures $I : q \mapsto iq$ and $J: q \mapsto jq$. Of course these anticommute and $I^2 = J^2 = -id$. Moreover, they are obviously isometries with respect to $\rho$ and both are orientation preserving.
Indeed, if $\{1, i, j, k\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4 \simeq \mathbb{H}$, the matrix expressions of these maps are
$$
I =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
J =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which you can easily verify to have determinant $1$.

This is the natural hypercomplex structure on $\mathbb{R}^4$ induced by an isomorphism with $\mathbb{H}$, to prove this structure is hyperkähler one needs to show that both $I,J$ are parallel with respect to the Levi-Civita connection. But on $\mathbb{R}^4$ this is trivial as, with respect to the Euclidean metric, its Levi-Civita connection is flat. Indeed, if $q : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ is a vector field
$$
(\nabla I)q = \nabla(Iq) - I \nabla q = d(Iq) - I d q = d I q + I dq -I d q = 0
$$
as $I$ is constant. As the same can be done for $J$, one concludes $\nabla I = \nabla J = 0$.

Comment: I think you are right. I also get an idea that I want to share with you. (I'm not sure if it is right.) At once I know $\mathbb{H}$ is just $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, I realize I only need to find hyperkahler structure on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ which is very easy.

Comment: Yes, because all the point of hyperkähler manifolds is to model spaces which locally behave as $\mathbb{H}^n$ (viewed as $\mathbb{H}$-module). This is basically the same idea of Kähler manifolds which, locally, behave as $\mathbb{C}^n$.